# el archivo .exe deja de funcionar en c++

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Estoy haciendo un blackjack en c++, el cual al compilarlo deja de funcionar el archivo .exe (blackjack.exe), he tratado de cambiar el main, las clases, todo pero sigue sin funcionar. Dejo el programa para ver si es ese el problema.

```
class Carta{
private:
    int numero; 
    string pinta;
    string color;

public:
    Carta (int numero, string pinta, string color) 
    {
        this->numero = numero;
        this->pinta = pinta;
        this->color = color;
    }
    void setNumero(int numero)
    {
        this->numero=numero;
    }
    void setPinta(string pinta)
    {
        this->pinta=pinta;
    }
    void setColor (string color)
    {
        this->color=color;
    }           
    int getNumero(){
        return this->numero;
    }               
    string getPinta(){
        return this->pinta;
    }       
    string getColor(){
        return this->color;
    }
};

class Baraja {
private:
    Carta *cartas[52];
public:
        Baraja (){
        for (int i=0; i<52;j++){
            cartas[i] = NULL;
            }

        for (int i=0; i<52;j++){
            if (i<13){
                for (int j=1; j<=13; j++){
                cartas[i]->setNumero(j);
                cartas[i]->setColor("negro"); 
                cartas[i]->setPinta("trebol"); 
                }
            }
            else if(i<26 && i>=13){
                for (int j=1; j<=13; j++){
                cartas[i]->setNumero(j);
                cartas[i]->setColor("negro");
                cartas[i]->setPinta("pica");
                }
            }
            else if(i<39 && i>=26){
                for(int j=1; j<=13; j++){
                cartas[i]->setNumero(j);
                cartas[i]->setColor("rojo");
                cartas[i]->setPinta("diamante");                    
                }
            }
            else{
                for(int j=1; j<=13; j++){
                cartas[i]->setNumero(j);
                cartas[i]->setColor("rojo");
                cartas[i]->setPinta("corazones");                   
                }
            }
            }
    }


    void barajar(){
        srand (time(NULL));
        for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++){
            int r = rand() % 52;
            Carta *aux = cartas[r];
            cartas[r] = cartas[i];
            cartas[i] = aux;
        }
    }

    Carta* getCartas(int i){
        return this->cartas [i];
    }

    Carta* robar(){
    Carta* aux = NULL;
    barajar();
    Inicio:
    if (cartas[52] == NULL){
        barajar();
        goto Inicio;
    }
    else{
    cartas [52] = aux;
    cartas [52] = NULL; 
    return aux;
    }
}



};

class Jugador{
protected:
    string nombre;
    int puntaje;

public:

    Jugador (string nombre, int puntaje) //constructor -inicio-
    {
        this->nombre = nombre;
        this->puntaje = 0;
    }
    void setNombre (string nombre)
    {
        this->nombre = nombre;
    }
    void setPuntaje (int puntaje)
    {
        this->puntaje = puntaje;
    }
    string getNombre()
    {
        return this->nombre;
    }
    int getPuntaje()
    {
        return this->puntaje;
    }                                    //constructor  -fin-                       

    void Jugar (Baraja *b){
        string respuesta;
        while (true){
        cout<<"Desea 'robar' o 'plantarse'?";
        cin>>respuesta;
        if (respuesta == "robar" || respuesta == "Robar"){
            if (puntaje >21){
                puntaje = 0;
                false;
            }
            else{
                if (b->robar()->getNumero() == 1){
                    b->robar()->setNumero(11);
                    puntaje = b->robar()->getNumero() + puntaje;
                }
                else{
                    puntaje = b->robar()->getNumero() + puntaje;
                }
            }               
        }
        else{
            if (puntaje >21){
                puntaje = 0;
                false;
            }
            else{
                puntaje = puntaje;
                false;
            }
        }
    }
}
};
class Crupier:public Jugador{
public:
Crupier(string nombre, int puntaje):Jugador(nombre, puntaje){
    this->nombre = "Crupier";
}
void Jugar (Baraja *b){
    while (puntaje<=16){
        if(b->robar()->getNumero() == 1){
            b->robar()->setNumero(11);
            puntaje = b->robar()->getNumero() + puntaje;    
        }
        else{
            puntaje = b->robar()->getNumero() + puntaje;
        }
    }
    if (puntaje>21){
        puntaje = 0;
    }
    else{
        puntaje = puntaje;
    }
}
};

int main(){   

Baraja* Inglesa = new Baraja();
Jugador* Jugador1 = new Jugador("Jugador uno",0) ;
Jugador* Jugador2 = new Jugador("Jugador dos",0);
Crupier* crupier  = new Crupier("Crupier",0);
int a=0;
int b=0;
int c=0;
Inglesa->barajar();
cout<<"Bienvenidos al Blackjack"<<endl;
for (int i = 0; i<2; i++){
    a = Inglesa->robar()->getNumero() + a;
    b = Inglesa->robar()->getNumero() + b;
    c = Inglesa->robar()->getNumero() + c;  
}
Jugador1->setPuntaje(a);
Jugador2->setPuntaje(b);
crupier->setPuntaje(c);

cout<<"Jugador 1 tu puntaje inicial es: "<<Jugador1->getPuntaje()<<endl;
Jugador1->Jugar(Inglesa);
cout<<"Jugador 2 tu puntaje inicial es: "<<Jugador2->getPuntaje()<<endl;
Jugador2->Jugar(Inglesa);
crupier->Jugar(Inglesa);

if(Jugador1->getPuntaje() > Jugador2->getPuntaje() && Jugador1->getPuntaje() > crupier->getPuntaje() )
{
    cout<<"El Jugador 1 es el ganador!";
}
if(Jugador2->getPuntaje() > Jugador1->getPuntaje() && Jugador2->getPuntaje() > crupier->getPuntaje() )
{
    cout<<"El Jugador 2 es el ganador!";
}
else{
    cout<<"Gana la mesa";
}
delete Inglesa;
delete Jugador1;
delete Jugador2;
delete crupier;

return 0;
}
```

Este compila, pero al mostrar consola aparece el mensaje de que "blackjack.exe a dejado de funcionar".

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en la lénea de código `Carta *cartas[52];` estás creando un arreglo bidimensional y solo estás definiendo solo 1 dimensión, cuando pones `cartas[i] = NULL;` no estás asignando memoria, estás diciendo que vale 0.

la solución es simplemente alocar bien la memoria con un simple `for` asignando 13 cartas, ya que son 4 palos.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++) {
    cartas[i] = new Carta[13];
}
```

Una nota... utiliza `this` solo cuando tengas ambigüedad, como con herencia o polimorfismo. No es un requerimiento utilizarlo tanto como haces tú.
Y además, puedes utilizar [destructores](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_constructor_destructor.htm) para evitarte hacer los `delete` al final.